# Who wrote that Americans believe their values are universal values?

Tags: united-states, cultural-history

I remember reading this statement (or something very close) years ago:

> Americans believe their values are universal values, which is the most
>   American value of all.

Who wrote this?
I want to say it was Walter McDougall in *Promised Land, Crusader State*, however I don't own the book, and can't find the quote in on-line searches (of that book, or otherwise).  In any case it's very possible I'm wrong and saw the quote elsewhere.

I realize the above point has probably been made many times, thus a related question: is there a particular author/speaker who is most often credited?

Comment: For the US, I wouldn't be surprised if you find hints of that idea in Tocqueville - and possibly even earlier than that. It might not the exact same quote, but the idea would likely be present. There's a non-null chance you'll find it amongst US revolutionaries, too. And in France a few years after during its own Revolution, and during the Enlightenment age before that, and amongst Christians before that still. A better quote might be: [proselytic] monotheistic cultures believe their values are universal values, which is the most [proselytic] monotheistic value of all.

Comment: Here is a closely related and recent quote: "As the late Singapore leader and statesman, Lee Kuan Yew, in an interview published in the March 5, 2013 Atlantic magazine, said:

“Americans believe their ideas are universal – the supremacy of the individual and free, unfettered expression. But they are not – never were.”"  (http://www.chinausfocus.com/culture-history/american-universalism-vs-chinese-nationalism/)